# Add www back into the URL if it's missing, using IIS7

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'd like to use IIS7 to rewrite my URL's.

I'd like it to make sure that the www is always there.

So...

http://willow-tree.co.uk/products/family-memory-box/p-416-13084/  ---->  http://www.willow-tree.co.uk/products/family-memory-box/p-416-13084/

No matter what protocol is in use (http / https), and no matter what comes after the .co.uk, I'd like it to always rewrite to the same URL, just with the www.

If it could be domain independent that would be even better, I have lots of websites and being able to copy and paste without changing anything would be great.

If this is done by redirect rather than rewrite it should be a 301.

Can anyone help..?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this regex, and for SEO sake it's better to use 301 redirect, but you have to have IIS url rewrite installed  :

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect willow-tree.co.uk to www" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^willow-tree.co.uk$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.willow-tree.co.uk/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

beware, this is the example for http only !

here is a blog post with some alternatives:

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/27/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www.aspx

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not an answer, as long as it is primarily just a link. Alternatively, you could explain the solution in your answer here by editing it, then simply leave the link to the blog post as a reference. As it is, it is likely to be deleted as 'not an answer'.